# How to use XOR in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to perform an XOR to find if one of two booleans a and b is true but not both. Searching for XOR in Kotlin gave me this answer

> #### `infix fun xor(other: Boolean): Boolean`
>
> Performs a logical xor operation between this Boolean and the other one. [source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/xor.html)

I'm still confused on how to implement this

Comment: you use it like this: `a xor b`

Comment: I find that interesting that Kotlin does not use `^` operator. Good Question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's an extension that can be invoked on any `Boolean`. You can use it like this:

```
true.xor(false)
```

or this:

```
true xor false
```

The last one works since the function is defined as [`infix`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation).

Other similar extensions defined on [`Boolean`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean/index.html) are `and`, `or` and `not`:

```
//very useful example
true.not().or(true).and(false).xor(true)
```

Answer (score 5):

find the single number in the array that every element has a duplicate except one.

```
var a = 0
for (i in numsArray){
    a = a xor i
}
return a
```

eg. input = [2,2,1]
out = 1

Comment: This won't exactly work on the function signature that the OP posted, which only accepts boolean arguments. But it does answer the question title.